# python, set terminal type in pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a script which uses pexpect to start a CLI program. It works a bit like a shell where you get a prompt where you can enter some commands.

The problem I have, I think, is that this program uses a coloured prompt.

This is what I do

```
import pprint
import pexpect

1 a = pexpect.spawn('program')
2 a.expect("prompt>")
3 print "---------start------------"
4 print(a.before)
5 a.sendline("command")
6 a.expect("prompt>")
7 print "---------before------------"
8 pprint.pprint(a.before)
9 print "---------after------------"
10 pprint.pprint(a.after)
```

This is the output:

```
> python borken.py
---------start------------
A lot of text here from the enjoying programs start-up, lorem ipsum ...  
---------before------------
' \x1b[0m\x1b[8D\x1b[K\x1b[1m\x1b[34m'
---------after------------
'prompt>'
```

For some reason the first prompt colour coding borkens up things and a.before at line 8 is garbled, normal print does not work,  even if I see that the command at line 5 actually produced a lot of output.

Does someone know what the problem could be, or is it possible to set the terminal type in pexpect to avoid the colours?

I am using tcsh shell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. csl's answer set me on the right path.

pexpect has a "env" option which I thought I could use. like this:

```
a = pexpect.spawn('program', env = {"TERM": "dumb"})
```

But this spawns a new shell which does not work for me, our development environment 
depends on a lot of environmental variables :/

But if I do this before spawning a shell:

```
import os
os.environ["TERM"] = "dumb"
```

I change the current "TERM" and "dumb" does not support colours, which fixed my issue.

Comment: any idea why spawn with env=xxx argument does not work here?

Comment: Looks like the specified env is all the process gets, which means it won't get any other environment variables, such as `PATH`. This seems to be a badly designed API. The correct usage for most people would be to clone os.environ and pass that after modification, something like: `env = dict(os.environ); env["TERM"] = "dump";  a = pexpect.spawn('program', env=env)`

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find anything in [the pexpect documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) for setting terminals, but you could probably start your program explicitly with a shell, and then set the terminal type there:

```
shell_cmd = 'ls -l | grep LOG > log_list.txt'
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', shell_cmd])
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

You could try something like

```
child = pexpect.spawn('TERM=vt100 /bin/bash', ['-c', shell_cmd])
```

You can also start bash with --norc and similar to avoid reading the initialization files.   Check out the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: This did not work,
I get:
    raise ExceptionPexpect ('The command was not found or was not executable: %s.' % self.command)
ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: TERM=vt100.

I don't know if it's because I use tcsh shell. :/