# ssh with winpexpect

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I've been trying to run this command to ssh from a .py on a Windows platform:

```
child = winpexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % ('myID','m.y.i.p'))
```

It should function similarly to pexpect, but I receive this error:

```
pexpect.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: ssh.
```

I've confirmed that C:\rhcygwin\bin is in my Path. Any suggestions on how to instruct the .py file to locate the ssh command?

edit: I switched my approach: ran this code in my .py

```
    command = ['bash', '-c', './myssh.sh']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

it's very rudimentary but it will connect successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358783/python-set-terminal-type-in-pexpect

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, pexect does not actually work on windows. There was a partial port attempt, but it was broken the last time I checked it.

If you want to automate doing something over ssh with python on windows, you will probably have better luck with the [paramiko library](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). There are [good docs](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/), but you will need to compile pycrypto, or else get a [precompiled binary](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml).

Comment: Thanks @SpencerRathbun, and for posterity: if you can get pycrypto/paramiko built, it's a very clean solution to this problem. I asked a similar question yesterday, and useful paramiko code was provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147548/executing-a-bash-script-in-python. As for my part, I have had no luck building a pycrypto library on my machine, and I've tried many guides.

Comment: @gortron I ran into the same problem getting it to compile on windows, but I found a precompiled lib which worked. You'd think that compiling would be easier than it is...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the winspawn method, and specify the .exe extension:

```
child = winpexpect.winspawn('ssh.exe %s@%s' % ('myID','m.y.i.p'))
```